# Configuring a Linux Wi-Fi access point to redirect a one-word URL to http://192.168.42.1:8888

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, hostapd, avahi

I've created a Wi-Fi access point on a Linux box (thanks to hostapd). I'm trying to make it easy for clients to access the Freenet service that's running on said box.

Ideally, the user would be able to log into the Wi-Fi access point and navigate to a URL such as 'freenet' or 'freenet.local'.

I'm thinking that the solution involves/requires avahi, dnsmasq, iptables, and perhaps nginx.

Although it would be lovely if someone explained in detail how it would be done, I'll be quite happy with a response that merely explains which tools are needed and why.

Comment: I defined www/ for that with DNS...in the DNS server that I give them with my DHCP